# Python reading file - NULL marks

Tags: python

I've got problem while going through Zed's guidebook.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "we're going to erase %r." % filename
print "if you don't want that hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "if you want that, hit RETURN"

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'r+')

print "Truncating the file, Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write this to file."
target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n" % (line1,line2,line3))

print target.read()

print "And finally, we close it"
target.close()
```

Afterr adding new content to my file ( with r+ in my open ) I'm gettig almost 4000 NULL characters which I can see in my notepad, besides my newly added content. This makes my file just blank page on the prompt. Where's the point?

Comment: Before the  `target.read()` - put a `target.flush()` to ensure all data is written and a `target.seek(0)` to put the pointer back to the start of the file

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior. The resulting file does not have any extra characters. (Although as an aside, the file must already exist, or else this code won't work, due to the `r+`). What is it you're typing?

Comment: Why not just open the file with `w` as the mode, which would truncate the file implicitly?

Comment: Wow, I was very surprised, but starting with a file with 'x'*4000, the file is totally corrupted on windows with junk after the written string and appended after the original x's. Linux works fine. @JonClements suggestion works great, btw.

Comment: Ah, I'm on Ubuntu, so that would explain why it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Worked well for me :)